# Unresolved dependency issue for JUnit tests with Gradle project in VS Code's Java Test Runnner

Tags: visual-studio-code, junit5

I cannot run my JUnit tests, which are part of a Gradle-based Java project, in VS Code using the Java Test Runner. I get a dependency resolution error when I run test:

```
message: Unresolved dependency: org.junit:junit-bom:5.6.2; code: 0; resource: /Users/tdean-vital/Development/vitreaauthorization/build.gradle;
```

I do not get this error when I run from the Gradle command line - All tests run. I have run from a Mac using multiple versions of Gradle. I have also run in the gradle:4.1.1-jre-11 Docker image. All attempts succeed *except* running from within the VS Code Java Test Runner.

I have tried explicitly adding a dependency on `org.junit:junit-bom:562` to my Gradle build projects, but that gave me the same error.

Any suggestions on how to identify and fix this issue so that I can run my tests from within VS Code?

Comment: Fighting this very same issue right now. Did you get to fix the issue for you?